# Want to Join three table but not work [Eloquent]

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to

SELECT events.id = scan.event_id IF Scan.student_id MATCH user.student_id SHOW events.id and events.name

But my code dint work, it blank screen nothing happen to show
so blind :|

Controller

```php
    public function pdftranscript($id)
    {
        $users = DB::table('users')
            ->join('scan', 'users.student_id', '=', 'scan.student_id')
            ->join('events', 'scan.event_id', '=', 'events.id')
            ->select('users.*', 'events.m_event_name', 'scan.event_id')
            ->get();
```

This blade

```php
        @foreach($user as $user)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$user->student_id}}</td>
            <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
            @foreach($event as $event)
            <td>{{$event->m_event_name}}</td>
            @endforeach
        <tr>
        @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you could `dd($users)` in your controller to check whether you have got a successful query. Then in blade, it should be:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$user->student_id}}</td>
        <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$user->m_event_name}}</td>
    <tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You already took the values in `$users` variable..No need for the second foreach loop.

```
@foreach($users as $user)
<tr>
    <td>{{$user->student_id}}</td>
    <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
    <td>{{$user->event_id}}</td>
    <td>{{$user->m_event_name}}</td>
<tr>
@endforeach
```